# Employer is paying me hourly, but not paying me overtime

Tags: texas, labor

Can an employee be Exempt and hourly?  Currently I work for a private company in Houston, TX as an Director of Nursing - Case Manager, I get paid hourly, but don't get paid overtime. Can anyone please advise? Thank you

Comment: If you do not get paid for overtime, why do you work overtime?

Answer (score 3):

[This Dept. of Labor page](https://webapps.dol.gov/elaws/whd/flsa/screen75.asp) indicates that executive, administrative and professional employees are in the exempt category, and the corresponding regulation [29 CFR §541.200](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c380650f19fd6a02537df3c420e850aa&mc=true&node=sp29.3.541.c&rgn=div6) agrees, as long as you make at least $684 per week on a [fee basis or salary basis](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=&SID=c380650f19fd6a02537df3c420e850aa&mc=true&n=pt29.3.541&r=PART&ty=HTML#sp29.3.541.g). Since apparently your pay depends on the number of hours that you work, you are not an exempt employee